# Spring Boot Error No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to put together a spring boot (2.1.4) REST application.  When I try to start the application in Eclipse I'm getting the following error and I'm not sure the issue as I've done similar projects in the past that have worked:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'claimController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'claimService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'claimService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field claimService in com.hms.vector.datasink.controller.ClaimController required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Here is my Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.hms.vector.datasink" })
public class DataSinkRestApplication {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run(DataSinkRestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ClaimController {

    @Autowired
    ClaimService claimService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/inbound/claim/insert", consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> insertClaim(@RequestBody String messageBody) {
        claimService.insertClaim(messageBody);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

And here is the service module:

```
@Service
public class ClaimService {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void insertClaim(String messageBody) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(env.getProperty("sql.insert.statement"));

        ClaimInput input = parseMessage(messageBody);

        ** set query parameters **

        query.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

Right now I'm just trying to get this to run locally in Eclipse and have not tried to deploy to any server.  I'm at a loss as to what could be missing.  Any help on what could be missing would be appreciated.  If I need to provide additional information please let me know.

**EDIT**

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hms.vector.datasink</groupId>
    <artifactId>data-sink</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>data-sink</name>
    <description>Data syncing service for HMS Vector</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8181

#Datasource Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://<db server host name>:1433;database=eim_db;integratedSecurity=true;
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=<user id>
spring.datasource.password=<password>

#Hibernate Configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dbo
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

#Tomcat Connection Pool Configuration
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
```

**ADDITIONAL EDIT **

Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1090) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:580) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:711) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:684) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:180) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.hms.vector.datasink.DataSinkRestApplication.main(DataSinkRestApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
```

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml or build.gradle file if it is there in your project ?

Comment: Also, can you provide your properties or yml config file?

Comment: pom.xml and application.properties have been added to the original post.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks ok... can you also provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: @EnableAutoConfiguration on a controller is strange. (It should be already on as you have @SpringBootApplication) But this is just a guess.

Comment: It's strange, but I doubt it's that since he has already the `@SpringBootApplication` as you said. I have a guess, but I need the full stacktrace to confirm

Comment: I commented out @EnableAutoConfiguration just to check and there was no change.  I set debug=true in my application.properties file and re-ran.  I've added the stack trace I got to the original post.

Comment: Is this the full stacktrace? No caused by?

Comment: Do you have a JPA configuration? like persistence.xml. If the EntityManager fails on creation, then it is not available as a spring bean

Comment: But he's using Spring Data JPA with Spring Boot 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this

```
<exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
     <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
```

or add another connection pool dependency.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer although all of the suggestions made were helpful.  This got me pointed in the right direction...though it uncovered some other changes I had to make.  Ultimately, after removing the exclusion as mentioned above, I had to do the following:  1) Add sql_auth.dll to classpath 2) Change to a 32-bit JRE from 64-bit and 3) Upgrade to the latest version SQL Server driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories` to your `DataSinkRestApplication` class.

You should remove the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from your controller too. It's also a good idea to avoid using the `@ComponentScan` annotation if you do not need it specifically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions.  Certainly help keeps the code cleaner.  Much appreciated.